# MySQL: Cannot Seem to Call Simple Stored Procedure -- Hitting Runtime Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, runtime

I have a Products table shown below:

```
 product_id  | low_fats | recyclable |
+-------------+----------+------------+
| 0           | Y        | N          |
| 1           | Y        | Y          |
| 2           | N        | Y          |
| 3           | Y        | Y          |
| 4           | N        | N          |
```

I want to create a simple stored procedure in MySql using the syntax below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
BEGIN
    SELECT *  FROM Products;
END; 

CALL GetAllProducts;
```

But when I run the above code I get the following error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL GetAllProducts' at line 18"

What am I doing wrong?  How do I fix it?

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: How do I tell what my client is?

Comment: you show some mysql syntax; what are you doing to run it?  e.g. using the mysql command (the mysql command line client) or mysql workbench or something else